# SQL row order in query

Tags: mysql, sql

If you are given a query is there a way to determine if you can always get a return in a particular order? Like if you had to return by SSN or name or price,can you guarantee a way in MySQL to get a query to return by SSN?

Comment: Of course: Define an `ORDER BY` clause in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can you **guarantee** a way in MySQL to get a query to return by SSN?

```
...
ORDER BY ssn
```

That's the only way.

There are many people that try to be clever, and try to get a database engine to return rows in a certain order without specifying an `ORDER BY` clause, as if that would somehow optimize something. Don't! Just don't! That's just a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Would the order operator go at the very end of the query search or at the beginning? select Ssn, fname, lname, bdate AS birth_date from schema.employee where sex='M' AND Dno =5; <- this is what I have so far

Comment: Yes, at the end. Just try it, you'll see.